# AWS Lambda Chalice: "The request could not be satisfied" Error

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, chalice

I want my lambda function to return the response of another lambda function invoked via `AWS API Gateway`.

Both functions are deployed by `Lambda Chalice` to different APIs.

When the first function sends a request to the 2nd functions API endpoint, I am getting an error response saying that "The request could not be satisfied".

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit to include some code as requested; shortened for brevity:**

```
@app.route('/verify_user_token', methods=['GET'], cors=True)
def verify_user_token():
    request = app.current_request
    params = request.query_params or {}

    # do your things here; if all goes well:

    r = requests.get(ANOTHER_AWS_API_GATEWAY_ENDPOINT_URL, data=params)

    return r.text
```

Comment: Can you include the code you're using to execute your Lambda? Also, ensure that you've set the Lambda Permissions to allow executions of Lambda 2 by Lambda 1.

Comment: Lambda1 is calling Lambda2 via an API endpoint, not invoking the function directly, thus there is no need for lambda execution permission.

Comment: Ahhh, ok, that's changes things. You wouldn't happen to be using an API Gateway Custom Domain Name as well would you?

Comment: No custom domain names, I'm using the domains and endpoint urls provided by default, such as: https://xyz1234.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/api

Comment: Do you have API keys enabled for this endpoint?

Comment: If I get what you are asking right, there are no keys required by neither endpoints. I can access them both without any keys, for example, via browser, issuing a GET request.

Comment: Can you invoke the Lambda2 via an API endpoint from cUrl or Postman?

Comment: yes @KaHouIeong